# informaçao- diferenca de onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

ola, estou a usar onclick e estou com uma duvida visto que das duas formas funciona.
qual é a diferença entre:

```
onclick="functionA(); functionB();"
```

para

```
onclick="functionA(), functionB(),"
```

Answer (score -2):

O ponto e vírgula é utilizado para terminar uma instrução. A vírgula pode ser usada para juntar várias atribuições de variáveis ou para juntar várias expressões em operações que requerem apenas uma expressão.